# C - Hashing a void type?

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I've made my own implementation of a `HashMap`/`HashTable` (i know they are different but it's irrelevant for this question).

In this implementation, I'd like it to be very flexible. I want to be able to store ints, structs, chars, strings, etc all as keys or values without having to change the code of my algorithms. For example, in Java I can just do:

`HashMap<Integer, MyPersonalClass>` and it will just work. In C, I know there is no direct equivalent except `void*`. The issue is, if I have:

```
/* Node structure. */
struct hm_Node
{
    void *key, *value;
    struct hm_Node *next;
};
```

As the Node(s) that make up my `HashMap/HashTable`, then my `hash()` method needs to somehow parse the `key` correctly. So far I've only looked up an algorithm for `char*`.

Is there something like:

```
// This may not be valid code, just using it as an example

unsigned int hash(void *ptr)
{
    switch(typeof(ptr)) // I know ptr is of type void*
    {
    case char*: ... break;
    case char: ... break;
    case int: ... break;
    }
}
```

How does that work exactly? I'm just trying to avoid having a whole different implementation for a HashMap of X, Y, and Z types. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to C. Nothing is magic, you bring your own muscle.

Comment: You can't extract the type `void *` is 'hiding' (e.g. with `(void *)&something`).

Comment: @KerrekSB So.... what do I do? Let's say I want to have multiple `HashMaps`, each of different types for the `key`. One `key` will be `double` and the other is `string`. Surely I'm not going to copy paste my entire `HashMap.c` and `HashMap.h` and make a `HashMapForDoubles.c` and `HashMapForDoubles.h`

Comment: @Hatefiend: No, you don't, but you need to be prepared to put *a lot of work* into this. Basically, you need to implement an ad-hoc vtable, and create all the relevant accessor functions (add, find, delete) for each type. Then, for each concrete type that you want to use, you populate a vtable with the respective accessor functions, and you pass that vtable to your generic hash table algorithms.

Comment: A few things. What is an `ad-hoc vtable`? Also, why would I need an `add` `find` and `delete` method for each individual type? My `put` method just creates a `Node` which has `void*` to the `key` and `value` of whatever is being placed. Surely it's the `hash` method that needs to account for all the different types, not any of the other methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the implementation of, for example `qsort`:They let the user provide the comparison function in order to be able to implement arbitrary sorts.

You can go the same way by letting the user provide a proper hash function through a function pointer - If you want, you can supply them with some pre-built hash functions for standard types they can re-use.

Comment: Just to be sure, is [this](http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/qsort.c) the code you are talking about?

Comment: @Hatefiend Yep, that is what I was talking about - Maybe there's not much *code* to re-use for your purpose, but definitely the *concept*.

Comment: Which part of this source code do you see it somehow allowing me to supply it data that changes how it functions?

Comment: @Hashfiend `qsort` does not need to know what it is actually sorting. It receives one argument called `cmp`- That is a pointer to a user-supplied function that needs to return >, < and == conditions. Your hash init function could just as well receive a user-supplied hash function that you'd store internally and would be called by your code to calculate the hash. Other arguments you 'd need the user to supply are `cmp` (compare, just like `qsort` does) and the size of one element.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I actually looked up function pointers and it was very much so the key to this problem :)